# Tax on US income for work days spent in India

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, india, non-resident

I moved to US in 30th-May-2019 on work visa and I spent 3 weeks working in India in December (my salary was still generated in the US)

Would some of my US income be allocated to India in this case? And would I need to pay taxes on this income in India?

EDIT: I am a resident in US and non-resident in India.

Comment: Were you in India before you moved to the US? Did you earn any money there?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes I was in India and was employed in India

Comment: We have a site specifically for [expatriates.se] which might get you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the details of Indian taxation but let me explain how their normally works.

It is normal that in a year when you move between countries you file a tax return in both. You should first  determine where you are resident for tax purposes in the year in question.  Each country has its own rules and you may be resident in one or the other or both (or neither if you are really lucky).

You indicate that you are resident in the US but not India for tax purposes. This means you have to file taxes in the US, and non-resident earning 250,000 rupees in India also have to file. So you must file in both countries.

You need to declare your entire income on both tax returns. There may be a difference in how you declare foreign income compared with domestic. Your US income probably still counts as foreign, even for the time you were in India while earning it, but check the rules carefully.

There is an agreement which means that you will probably not be taxed twice on the same income, but both countries want to know about it.

It may be worth your while to get a professional to do your tax returns this year.

Comment: I know that I am resident in US and non resident in India. Does this help you answer the question?

Comment: It does. Please edit that info into the question and I will update the answer. I don't know if you have to file a tax return in India if you have earned there but are not resident.

Comment: Updated the question. I also know I need to file a tax return in India because I had income in India before moving to US. However my question is about the income I earned when I was employed in US but spent 3 weeks in India.

Comment: As I say in the answer: You need to declare your entire income on both tax returns.Your US income probably still counts as foreign, even for the time you were in India while earning it, but check the rules carefully.